# How to make C# able to see "template like type" T in structure builtin function like in C++?

Tags: c#, function, templates, structure

i have this code function in C++ to convert different objects to bytes array:

```
template <typename T>
static void GetBytesArrayFrom(T value, BYTE *out_array)
{
    union BytesConverter
    {
        T value;
        BYTE bytes_array[sizeof(T)];
    };

    BytesConverter bc;
    bc.value = value;

    memcpy(out_array, bc.bytes_array, sizeof(T));
}
```

now i am trying to make same function in C#, but have a problem:

```
public void GetBytesFrom<T>(T value, byte[] out_array) where T : object
{
    struct BytesConverter
    {
        [FieldOffset(0)] 
        T value; //T is unknown here
        [FieldOffset(0)] 
        byte[] bytes_array = new byte[sizeof(T)]; //and here
    }

int test = 0;
}
```

and it appear to be i can't define struct inside function at all.
How then it possible to do same cool conversion function in C#?

Comment: What are you trying to do with a object to byte[] conversion? Serialization?

Comment: @ken2k, kinda yes, but i know about serialization, but i don't like the way it work. it adds field names to binary data, assembly info and etc. i need just plain bytes that represents structure / class / type data same as in C++

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
static void GetBytes<T>(T obj, byte[] data)
{
    unsafe
    {
        fixed (byte* pData = data)
        {
            Marshal.StructureToPtr(obj, (IntPtr)pData, false /*careful...*/);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Kosmos: Sure. However, **make sure** that `T` does **not have embedded references** (whether directly or indirectly). If it does, then you would have to use `Marshal.DestroyStructure` on the pointer when you are done with it -- but you won't be able to, because the array might have moved in memory (and thus been invalidated). Be careful...

Answer (score 2):

FWIW having a `struct` explicitly defined locally in a method is not possible in C# (might be in MSIL and thus in other .NET languages, but I'm not sure).

However, in .net you can use the [`Buffer.BlockCopy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.buffer.blockcopy.aspx) function which essentially is the same as `memcpy`, but only works for primitive types (int, double, char, byte, etc.). For other types, you need to use `Array.Copy`.

My C++ is a little rusty, but I think that your C++ function is at best platform/compiler specific when it comes to non-primitive types.